# Efficiently find the depth of a graph from every node

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a problem where I am to find the minimum possible depth of a graph which implies that I have to find the maximum depth from each node and return the least of them all. Obviously a simple DFS from each node will do the trick but when things get crazy with extremely large input, then DFS becomes inefficient (time limit). I tried  keeping the distance of each leaf to the node being explored in memory to but that didn't help much.

How do I efficiently find the minimum depth of a very large graph. It is worthy of note that the graph in question has *no cycle*.

Comment: Are you trying to find the [graph center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_center) of an undirected tree graph?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Yeah, something like that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find the graph centre/center of an undirected tree graph you could:

1. Do a DFS to find a list of all leaf nodes O(n)
2. Remove all these leaf nodes from the graph and note during the deletion which new nodes become leaf nodes
3. Repeat step 2 until the graph is completely deleted

The node/nodes deleted in the last stage of the algorithm will be the graph centres of your tree.

Each node is deleted once, so this whole process can be done in O(n).

Comment: The number of iterations would then be the return value? Right?

Comment: If there are multiple nodes deleted at the last stage, then the answer will be the number of iterations.  However, if there was a single node deleted at the last stage, then the answer will be the number of iterations -1.  (A tree A-B will be removed in 1 iteration and has depth 1, while a tree A will also be removed in 1 iteration and haa depth 0)

Comment: Am i  missing something or the last node to be deleted will always be the DFS's key ?

Comment: @tumasgiu not quite sure what you mean by the key of the DFS?  Perhaps you mean the starting point for the DFS?  If so, then note that you may have started the DFS from a leaf node, so it is possible for the starting point to be one of the first nodes to be deleted.

Comment: Yeah, I meant the DFS start point. But in a undirected graph, there are no concept of leaf node, right ? I thought that the leaves you mentionned was the one "created" by the DFS

Comment: @tumasgiu I may not have the terminology correct - by leaf node I mean a node with degree 1, i.e. it only has one edge connected to it.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be looking for is the *diameter* / 2. You could compute the diameter of a tree as below and call it as `findDiameter(n, null)`, for an arbitrary node `n` of the tree.

```
public findDiameter(node n, node from) returns <depth, diameter>

    // apply recursively on all children
    foreach child in (neighbors(n) minus from) do
        <de, di> = findDiameter(child, n)

    // depth of this node is 1 more than max depth of children
    depth = 1 + max(de)

    // max diameter either uses this node, then it is 1 + the 2 largest depths
    // or it does not use this node, then it's the max depth of the neighbors
    diameter = max(max(di), 1 + max(de) + oneButLargest(de))
```

All you need to do is in the loop over the neighbors keep track of the largest diameter and the 2 largest depths.

Comment: from the definition of "diameter of a graph" as I read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(graph_theory)#Related_concepts), I doubt if this solves my problem. Can you please explain how this relates to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @OlayinkaSF The diameter `d` of a tree is the length of the longest path between two leafs. Consider the middle node `m` in that path (assuming `d` is even; if `d` is odd, there are 2 such nodes). The max depth from `m` is `d / 2` (its max depth has to be found along the longest path, or we would have a contradiction and some other path would be longer). For every other node, the max depth is at least `d / 2 + 1` (route it via `m` and then to one of the ends of the longest path). Hence, `m` is a graph center and the value you search for is `d / 2`.

Comment: I can confirm that it's a working solution.
However, to find depth you don't have to calculate diameter. 
And note, that this would only work properly for a graph with one connected component.